# Use LetsEncrypt SSL Certs with Express (MEANJS) Production Mode

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, meanjs, lets-encrypt

I'm using the Meanjs boilerplate. My LetsEncrypt certs works fine on dev mode and non node applications, but I'm can't make it work on prod mode.

The following message appears when I start the application:

```
 + Error: Certificate file or key file is missing, falling back to non-SSL mode
  To create them, simply run the following from your shell: sh ./scripts/generate-ssl-certs.sh
```

If I run `sh ./scripts/generate-ssl-certs.sh` untrusted self-signed certs are generated, but works only if I point them into nginx configuration too. Otherwise I get 502 error on Browser. BTW I need to use trusted certs.

If I try to copy my trusted LetsEncrypt certs to application path `config/sslcerts/` I'm also getting 502 error.

Cert files (links) from  `/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/`

```
cert.pem 
chain.pem
fullchain.pem
privkey.pem
```

Nginx error.log:

```
2016/11/02 23:50:28 [error] 26186#26186: *164 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8443/", host: "domain.com"
```

Comment: I would suggest let https-portal take care of those certs for you. The SSL certificates are obtained, and renewed from Let's Encrypt automatically. https://github.com/SteveLTN/https-portal